# Can I combine extension tubes and macro filters at once to give better macros?

Tags: macro, extension-tubes, macro-converter

I don't have a dSLR at the moment but am planning to buy one. Wanted to know the cheaper methods to shoot in macro. Will using macro filters and extension tubes concurrently increase the efficiency of the shot?